# Routing in OpenVPN in Azure

Tags: routing, openvpn, azure

I moved a working **OpenVPN** server from our on-premises infrastructure to **Azure**.

The configuration of the VPN server on-premises and on Azure are absolutely the same. Same settings, same IP range. The configuration is the same as the VPN server is in a VHD.

I just uploaded the same VPN server VHD to Azure. On-premises all VPN clients can ping all hosts in the internal VPN IP range and all hosts in the internal VPN range can ping all clients. In Azure, however, at least according to TCPDump, clients go to all hosts, but the hosts can't route back through the VPN server.

All routing tables are the same as the on-premises configuration. It's like Azure does not let me route back though the VPN server.

Has anyone else been in the same situation? Do I need to configure any routing using Azure cmdlets to get the hosts to route through the OpenVPN IP?

Answer (score 1):

Without providing any technical details, I will be guessing here.

Since the VMs inside Azure will have their own gateway that are most likely different than the setup that you have in your LAN,I would bet that the routes of the hosts inside your LAN is different than the routes of your hosts in Azure, I would take a look there first and yes, add whatever routs are missing (which in your case, should be the LAN subnet).

Assuming that you're using VNets in there, why not use a **VPN Gateway from Azure** it self? you'll get a better SLA from hosting your own VPN Solution, less operation headache too, and no need to configure routes on clients, you may read all about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/vpn-gateway/

**EDIT:**

If using OpenVPN is a must for you or if you don't want to use the Azure VPN gateway, Azure support the creation of "**User Defined Routes and IP Forwarding**" inside VNets, this is the kind of solution you should use if you're using a Virtual Appliance inside a VNet, which is in your case, the OpenVPN server, read all about it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-udr-overview/

Comment: Azure VPN doesn't support [OSX or Linux clients](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/4233968-either-add-point-to-site-sstp-vpn-clients-for-mac).